# Java, Instance Replace instead of Mock

Tags: java

Hi: Normally you use mock (java agent) to replace an object in the class.

For example:

```
public class ClassA{
  public ClassB realObjectB;
  public ClassC realObjectC;


  public void Method1(){
       realObjectC = new ClassC();
       realObjectB =  new ClassB(realObjectC);   
  }     

  ...

  ...
```

}

```
public class ClassB {


      public void ParticularInhereitedMethod(){
          many dependency objects involved...
      }  

}
```

of course, ClassB and ClassC have many other dependency, for example connection pool.

When I do testing, may I do:

```
 public class Mock extends ClassB{        

 @override  
 public class ParticularInhereitedMethod(){
      Make clean codes, no dependency.
 }
```

}

In test application:

```
   public class MainClass{

          public static void main(String[] args){
                  ClassA a = new ClassA();
                  ClassM m = new Mock();
                  a.realObjectB = m; 

                  manipulate m;
          }

   }
```

Is this above method works in real testing? Why do I have to use Java agent(byte code replacement)?

Comment: I think you are confusing the concept of mock objects and the way some libraries implement them. 
Mock objects are exactly what you show in your code, and you are not using a java agent. And they work. 
There are mocking libraries that are very powerful in generating mock objects for you. These may use java agents or similar things to build these objects.

Comment: Does my method wrong or right? Do I have to use mockito or use dependence injection suggested by following two answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a Mockito http://code.google.com/p/mockito/ and Spring injection to resolve your problem.

With mockito tou can declare the return parameter on an object from the parameters, with spring you can resolve the instance of the object at runtime

Comment: Does my method wrong or right? Do I have to use mockito or use dependence injection suggested by following two answers?

Comment: the proble of your method is a.realObjectB = m, in this way if the property should be private you are going to make it public only for test. I think you shoud Spring and invertion of control, so you can inject the right of your object.

Answer (score 1):

You may be finding difficult to mock out/replace as your objects are relatively complex.  I would look at ways to test them in a simpler manner and use dependancy injection to allow you replace their implementations without sub-classing.

Comment: Does my method wrong or right? Do I have to use mockito or use dependence injection suggested by following two answers?